# The rigged eye does not close completely

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones

I'm rigging the eyes of my character following this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CCGekumdLLU)

The mesh of the left eye deformed almost correctly. There is again something broken because the eye does not close completely and the bones move too far from their initial position. I would like to know what to do to fix it. I've attached two pics to show what happened.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

[image]

Comment: I found this clip rather helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMVxa9k0ZS0 It's quite a complicated setup but there are some tips you can use for simpler rigs -  the weight painting part is quite interesting. Another tip - I 'cheat' a bit on my own models, adjusting the mesh with the eye bones in closed position, and then see how it looks like when open. Sometimes it works just fine. Also expect someone will make an eye rig soon with the new bendy bones which should make the weight painting a breeze...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a weights problem.
This tutorial is quite advanced and relates to a dense mesh properly and evenly modeled because it's automatically weighted.
As I can see from your 2nd picture (in example) even the closer vertices of the lower eyelid don't follow exactly the closer bones: it means that those vertices are weighted also in other Bones/vertex groups. Probably your mesh needs some manual weighting to work properly: if a vertex is weighted (any value of weight) to a bone/vertex group only, it follows EXACTLY the bone movement.
The button assign gives to the selected vertices the weight indicated below (from 0.0 to 1.0). The button remove removes the selected vertices from the vertex group. The button select adds to the current selection all the vertices of that vertex group. The button deseletc removes from the current selection all the vertices of the vertex group (but those deselected vertices are still assigned and weighted to the current vertex group, so - if you click select - they appear again). In edit mode, press N for the properties tab, select a vertex and you can find the "vertex weight" tab that shows you all weights and all  vertex groups your vertex is in (sorry for my english, I'm from Italy).

Comment: hello man. can you explain to me why,when I remove vertices from a vertex group and then I click assign ; deselect ; select again --> I don't see any changes ? but when I go in object mode,sometimes I see the changes,sometimes not...

Comment: I edited the answer

Comment: Actually I configured the weight to 1.0 to all the vertex groups and I deselected the vertex that are too far away from the lower part of the eyelid. And it almost worked. Now the eyelid closes,but it's not perfect,yet...check here : http://psychonews.it/dati/2016-05-03_18-55-29.png ; if u want to give a look,this is the model : http://psychonews.it/dati/Pierino99.blend

Comment: I live in Italy,too :)

Comment: I can't download the .blend file.

Comment: why not ? I attached the blend file..

Comment: Makes firefox go crazy, then crash

Comment: I edited che question and i have attached the blend file on giant cow films.

Comment: Quello che non capisco è perché quando rimuovo dei vertici dai gruppi di vertici sembra che le modifiche non attecchiscono. Poi vado in pose mode e apro e chiudo l occhio e vedo che hanno preso.

Comment: forse perchè devi attivare sul modifier armature l'icona "display modifier in edit mode" (vicino alla macchina foto-render e l'occhio-viewport)

Comment: Sei riuscito a scaricare il modello ? Puoi dargli un occhiata ?

Comment: il tuo aiuto non ha funzionato,le modifiche che faccio al gruppo di vertici in edit mode non compaiono : guarda questo video : http://psychonews.it/dati/2016-05-04_15-14-59.mp4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39300/discussion-between-josh-sanfelici-and-marietto).